# Can I use interfaces to define a base expectation?

Tags: c#, interface

I have a set of Models that are paired with (almost) matching data structures in two large legacy projects; each project sits on either side of an API and so I wanted to create a "Globals" project that could be inherited by both to ensure some form of consistency, reduce the likely-hood of fires & start enforcing programming for interfaces and not implementations.

My plan was to use interfaces to create a sort of common ground that both could inherit but could deviate slightly from (due to data being needed on one side but not the other) however I've come across a problem with using them in this way when it comes to nesting.

Say I have two interfaces:

```
namespace Example.Interfaces
{
    public interface A
    {
        int X { get; set; }
        int Y { get; set; }
    }

    public interface B
    {
        int J { get; set; }
        List<A> KLM { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I want to use this use these in the Models I'll be looking at doing something like below.

```
namespace Example.Models
{
    public class Item : A
    {
        int X { get; set; }
        int Y { get; set; }
    }

    public class Container : B
    {
        int J { get; set; }
        List<Item> KLM { get; set; } // Wrong
    }
}
```

This is the point at which my expectations are proving to be entirely wrong (bad derpasaurus, go back to school!)

In the example above. Within `Container` I would expect to be able to define a `List<>` of `Item`s (as shown), as they inherit `A`; this is obviously not the case as I'm seeing warnings telling me that I should be defining `KLM` as `List<Interfaces.A>`.

If I make the changes that are being recommended by Visual Studio, I cannot then make an assignment of type `Item` to the field `KLM`, as shown below.

```
var derp = new Container
{
    J = 1
    KLM = new List<Item> { X = 123, Y = 456 }
};
```

Then I'm seeing the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Example.Models.Item' to 'Example.Interfaces.A'

My questions are:

- Can this actually be done, or is this impossible due to the potential loss of data caused by implicitly converting an `Item` to an `A`?
- Is there a better way of implementing a scaffold of base (shared) fields between two projects with divergent Models?
- Can I (should I) do any shoehorning to make this work?

Comment: So you `List<Item>` is exposed as a `List<A>` and someone comes along and does `KLM.Add(new SomethingElseThatImplementsAButIsntItem());`. Do you see the problem? Just because two types exhibit a particular implementation relationship, that does *not* mean that a third (generic) type parameterized by those two types exhibits the *same* implementation relationship.

Comment: Yeah you're spot on there, I made a mistake making that a list. Nesting the field of type `A` would have been much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work you need to change your interface:

```
public interface B<T> where T:A
{
    int J { get; set; }
    List<T> KLM { get; set; }
}
```

Here where condition of you interface forces classes that implement it to have a list of object that are of type A.

Now your interface can be implemented by your class:

```
public class Container : B<Item>
{
   public int J { get; set; }
   public List<Item> KLM { get; set; } 
}
```

If you want read access to interface `B` without knowing the concrete type you can modify this:

```
public interface B
{
    int J { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<A> KLM { get; }
}

public interface B<T> : B where T:A
{
    new List<T> KLM { get; set; }
}
```

And implementation:

```
public class Container : B<Item>
{
   public int J { get; set; }
   public List<Item> KLM { get; set; } 

   IEnumerable<A> B.KLM => KLM;
}
```